# How to use macros or metaprogramming to define multiple objects at the same time?

Tags: c++

Coming from a C# background with its powerful code generation system (`.tt` files), I felt immediately uncomfortable writing code like this by hand:

```
export enum class GrowableTextureAtlasInternalStorageType
{
    OneChannel,
};

constexpr GLenum internal_storage_for_growable_texture_atlas_internal_storage_type[] =
{
    GL_R8,
};

constexpr GLenum format_for_growable_texture_atlas_internal_storage_type[] =
{
    GL_RED,
};

constexpr GLenum pixel_type_for_growable_texture_atlas_internal_storage_type[] =
{
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
};
```

Ideally, I'd like a way to write something like this instead:

```
DEFINE_STORAGE_TYPE(OneChannel, GL_R8, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
```

and have it generate an `enum class` and a separate object (or more, like in my code), that contains the rest of the constants. Arrays let me easily index the `enum` in them, maps also work, etc.

How are things like these generally approached in modern C++? There are no limitations on the standard, I'm already using C++20 modules as seen above.

Edit for @Elliott specifically: In case it's not entirely clear from my question, the purpose of the question isn't to put my generated code inside a macro, it's to write a macro that allows me to easily add any amount of values to the various arrays in an error-proof way.

For example, if I were to call the macro like this (with maybe a wrapping set of macros if necessary):

```
DEFINE_STORAGE_TYPE(OneChannel, GL_R8, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
DEFINE_STORAGE_TYPE(Rgba, GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8);
```

I would expect the code generated to be:

```
export enum class GrowableTextureAtlasInternalStorageType
{
    OneChannel,
    Rgba,
};

constexpr GLenum internal_storage_for_growable_texture_atlas_internal_storage_type[] =
{
    GL_R8,
    GL_RGBA8,
};

constexpr GLenum format_for_growable_texture_atlas_internal_storage_type[] =
{
    GL_RED,
    GL_RGBA,
};

constexpr GLenum pixel_type_for_growable_texture_atlas_internal_storage_type[] =
{
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8,
};
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. The one-liner doesn't seem to have enough information to generate all the code above.

Comment: What do you think is missing?

Comment: Is the name `internal_storage_for_growable_texture_atlas_internal_storage_type` for example, fixed? Also, shorter names would be nice for the example :)

Comment: Yes, the structure is fixed. These things represent OpenGL parameters to store and transfer textures, they've been fixed for a long time.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks. It should be trivial with a macro, but I can't think of a way to do it in the language.

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++ macros, you can use something like a "lookup table" like so.

```
#define TABLE(m_)                                         \
    m_(OneChannel, GL_R8, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)       \
    m_(Rgba, GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8)

#define CHANNEL_SELECTOR(chan, width, color, type) chan,
#define WIDTH_SELECTOR(chan, width, color, type) width,

export enum class GrowableTextureAtlasInternalStorageType
{
    TABLE(CHANNEL_SELECTOR)
};

constexpr GLenum internal_storage_for_growable_texture_atlas_internal_storage_type[] =
{
    TABLE(WIDTH_SELECTOR)
};

#undef CHANNEL_SELECTOR
#undef WIDTH_SELECTOR
#undef TABLE

// The rest of the plug-in macros and structure definitions left as an exercise.
```

You then just modify the table when adding new stuff.

I don't like macros since they kind of make you think "backwards" :) Check out boost macros (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html) that provide a host of helper "macro-world" operations.

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the solutions I was considering, but it still requires a lot of manual boilerplate. I'm very interested in the boost solution if it can do it with one macro, do you know how that would look like?

Comment: It's "write once, maintain easily" kind of code. Instead of updating a bunch of structures, you just update a "table" instead. Makes maintenance and expansion easy :) With the "cost" of generator code; you can also pay it with a templated class in C++ (the answer w/ templates isn't super complete as StorageType isn't defined, but it'll work). For boost preprocessor: not as familiar with crafting these kinds of tables, but it not just one macro. Might be less verbose as they provide "iterators". https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using C++, you'd use templates:

```
using OneChannel = StorageType<GL_RED, GL_R8, std::uint8_t>;
using Rgba = StorageType<GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA, std::array<std::uint8_t, 4>>;
template AllStorageTypes<OneChannel , Rgba>; // Explicit instantiation
```

`StorageType` is a trivial template which just stores the parameters. `AllStorageTypes<Types...>` takes a variable-length list and creates your arrays etc by repeatedly looping over its arguments. `sizeof...(Types)` gets you your array sizes. Every initializer you use is a *braced-init-list* where template pack expansion works.

Comment: Hm, could you provide a fully working example? I don't think I quite see the declarations of those two types.